# backward euler method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Having abit of trouble, would be very grateful if someone could help.

Derive the backward Euler method for the problem:

$$\frac{du}{dt}=:d_tu=: \dot{u}=\lambda u    $$

$$ u(0)=u_0$$

any help would be much appreciated, many thanks

Comment: so please see if   this is  enough  for solve problem.if you would like any specific language,please indicate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know if it  is worth to post as  a answer,but  ok i will post it
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method

please read it

there is also  description of this method in matlab(i am assuming that  you are familiar  with matlab)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937183/matlab-code-help-backward-euler-method

Comment: oh right i see, it was just a proof, i see, thanks for your time

Comment: you are welcome.i am glad when  see that  i can help someone